# Array.Indexof confusion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hellos guys I am a beginner and have 2 classes. Class A has an Array that I need to access in Class B. I've searched through here for the past 36 hours trying different methods and this is what I ended up with any help?

This is the first Class with the Array

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Cli
{
    public string name;
    public int money;
};

public class BankManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static BankManager _instance;

    public static BankManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                GameObject go = new GameObject("BankManager");
                go.AddComponent<BankManager>();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public GameObject player;
    private string NaMe;
    public Bank[] banks = new Bank[1];
    public Cli[] clients = new Cli[1];

    void Awake()
    {
        _instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        banks[0] = new Bank("In But Not Out", 10000);
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        clients[0].money = 1000;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        PlayerController pName = player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        clients[0].name = pName.name;

    }
}
```

The array I am trying to access is the clients[]

```
public class AccessAtm : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Bank bank;
    public int clams;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        bank = BankManager.Instance.banks[0];
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            clams = Array.IndexOf(BankManager.Instance.clients, 
                other.GetComponent<PlayerController>().name);
            Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<PlayerController>().name);
        }
    }
}
```

The debug.log properly tells me I'm getting the player.name I believe my error is in either getting that instance of the array or in the indexof command

Comment: i should probably clarify clams is = -1 when i run this when it should be element 1 in the array

Comment: Nowhere do I see you actually *assign* clients[0] so `IndexOf` not finding it should be expected. Also given that the array is only length 1; it *better* not return 1 :) (btw, public fields and static references like this are *terrible* practice)

Comment: Not related to your question but you really should try to call `other.GetComponent<PlayerController>()` only once, save the result in a variable and use that varible twice in your function.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET While I agree about the statics (insetad he should use a pre-load scence to create the `MonoBehavior` and call `DontDistroyOnLoad(this.gameObject)` then use `GetComponent` in the `Awake` of the other script to get the manager) Unity3D requires you not to use properties and use public fields instead due to engine limitations with serialization.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i call clients[0].money and .name in the first classes void start and update

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the advice will get to refactoring once this is figured out.

Comment: That's different from actually assigning that element of the array...

Comment: @He is assigning it `banks[0] = new Bank("In But Not Out", 10000);` in `BankManager.Start()` With Unity3D `Start` is a initialization method that is called on the first frame of the game after the script has been enabled.

Comment: so im feeling really stupid then what would the fix be to call clients[0] = NaMe, 1000;

Comment: I would expect to see a new client created first, like `clients[0] = new Cli();` before assigning a property of the object: `clients[0].money = 1000;`

Comment: ok will try that

Comment: @RufusL Because `Cli` is seralizeable `clients[0]` is generated by the the designer automaticly while you are in the editor.

Comment: so does that mean that wasnt the fix?

Comment: @RufusL yea seem to still be returning -1 on clams with that line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `IndexOf` expects you to pass a instance of `Bank` for the 2nd parameter of

```
clams = Array.IndexOf(BankManager.Instance.clients, 
            other.GetComponent<PlayerController>().name);
```

you are passing it a string.

You need to use something else to search for it, the easist solution would be use a for loop.

```
var clients = BankManager.Instance.clients;
var otherName = other.GetComponent<PlayerController>().name;
int foundAt = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < clients.Length; i++)
{
    if(clients[i].name == otherName)
    {
        foundAt = i;
        break;
    }
}
claims = foundAt;
```

Comment: sorry for being such a noob but can you explain this for(int i = 0; i < clients.Length; i++)
{
    if(clients[i].name == otherName)
    {
        foundAt = i;
        break;